# (Win subsytem linux/lxss/python virtualenv) How to use Windows apps to edit WSL/LXSS files under Python Virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lxss

I wonder if it possible to edit files under lxss virtualenv?

What I know is that I should be able edit lxss files with certain configuration.

However, it seems that I cannot edit lxss files in a python virtualenv with VS Code or similar editor (no permission/cannot overwrite).

Does it make any difference if I'm using a virtualenv or is it the same as accessing lxss files?

EDIT: Windows 10 OS and VSCode in Windows. LXSS version is Xenial.

Comment: Hi, added requested details to the post. Yes, I've been doing some research and it seems that there's a gap between windows ACL and lxss permissions.

Comment: WSL files SHOULD NOT be edited with any Windows program. But you can edit with VScode then you should change file permission with `chmod 664 *`